# ArrayList object sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, object, arraylist

I have to sort ArrayList which consists of objects. Object: ID, Quantity. The ArrayList should be sorted by ID. How to implement this?

```
ItemIdQuantity = new ItemIdQuantity (ID, Quantity);

ItemIdQuantity.Sort(); // where must be sorting by ID
```

Comment: PascalCase `Sort` is a clue it's C# and not Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class IdComparer : IComparer  {
  int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y) {
      return Compare((ItemIdQuantity)x, (ItemIdQuantity)y);
  }
  public int Compare(ItemIdQuantity x, ItemIdQuantity y) {
      return x.ID - y.ID;
  }
}

arrayList.Sort(new IdComparer());
```

Comment: I put the first line of your code in to a new class in Eclipse and it first complains about ':' saying it expected extends, and then when I put that in, it complained IComparer cannot be resolved to a type.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `public class IdComparer implements Comparator<MyObjectType> {` appears to be ok, but I'd still like to understand your syntax. Thanks

Comment: @Mark: The original version of the question did not have the Java tag. Apparently, a third party has added such a tag. I answered assuming the language is C#.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is Java:

- If the `ItemIdQuantity` class implements [`Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) based on the ID field, use [`Collections.sort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) with the list as single parameter.
- Otherwise, implement a [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares the objects using their ID, and use it as second paramter to `Collections.sort()`.